# NDSolve and DSolve solutions

Tags: differential-equations

Sorry for this probably trivial question, but I'm at a loss with this simple problem and the way Mathematica handles it.
It's about a free-falling object, dropped by a height of 10, starting with zero initial velocity.
Applying the conservation of energy (and assuming $g=1$) I can write the following differential equation

```
DSolve[{z'[t]^2 == 2 (10 - z[t]), z[0] == 10}, z[t], t]
```

That gives the expected result

```
{{z[t] -> 1/2 (20 - t^2)}}
```

But if, instead, I use the NDSolve command I get this different result

```
s = NDSolve[{z'[t]^2 == 2 (10 - z[t]), z[0] == 10}, z[t], {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] /. s], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: NDSolve result]

Somehow it makes sense since I'm telling Mathematica that the velocity is function of the height (and not of time) and with a zero initial velocity the position doesn't change so velocity will stay zero and position will stay constant... (Galileo used this argument to prove that for a falling body it's not $v=k\cdot h$ but rather $v=k\cdot t$). Anyway I can't thoroughly understand the different behavior of NDSolve and DSolve and how to avoid this possible problem in other differential equations (more complex than this one)

Comment: `z[t] -> 10` is actually a correct solution that `DSolve` fails to return here.

Comment: That solution is of course not physical because it has zero acceleration. To get a physical solution with NDSolve, it would be best to simply include the acceleration (`z''[t]`) in the phrasing of the problem. Alternatively, you can use a slightly perturbed initial condition. Note that there will be two solutions as this formulation doesn't encode the sign of the velocity.

Comment: Yes. I didn't realize that subtlety before. Energy conservation is respected in a physical motion, but it's not enough to make the machine start chugging. So I must be careful when using something like $K+U=E_0$ as a differential equation...